# ADO.NET Whitespace padding problem

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I've switched from LINQ to SQL to ADO.NET (with MSSQL) because of [a problem I described earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172329/linq-to-sql-filtering-results-in-a-datagridview), but I also ran into a weird problem using ADO.NET.

I import data from an excel worksheet using excel interop and I place its contents to the database. I trim everything that gets inserted, so this is not (supposed to be) the source of the problem.

When I view the contents of the table using DataGridView, what I see is that every cell has got loads of whitespaces after the text they contain. Screenshot below.

[alt text http://shadow.crysis.hu/so_adonet_whitespaces.png](http://shadow.crysis.hu/so_adonet_whitespaces.png)

I used Google to find a solution, but the only usable result I found was to

```
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

I did it (so I set ANSI_PADDING OFF before I began to import and set it back ON when I was done), but nothing changed. Oh, I'm using NCHAR(255) as field type.

If I trim the contents I display in the datagridview, it's fine, but if possible, I'd like to avoid this overhead (after all, I have to loop over ALL the rows and columns displayed, and since I'm working with a lot of data - a few thousand rows - it's not the best solution). What should I do?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using an `nchar(255)`, which is a static length of 255. Try changing the column to `nvarchar(255)`.

An `nchar(255)` will always give you 255 characters. Those that aren't used are filled in by whitespace (0x20 in ASCII aka a space). `nvarchar(255)` will allocate 255 characters when initialized, but only use the characters necessary.

In this case, you want `nvarchar(255)`, since you have a variable-length string.

Answer (score 1):

Try NVARCHAR instead of NCHAR.

Answer (score 1):

NCHAR is a fixed length field. Using NVARCHAR as your data type would keep you from getting the spaces.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, Eric gave the most detailed answer, so I accepted his answer, but you got a +1 as well.