# Filtering out with PHP from an array containing pdo/sql fetched results

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo, count

I am fetching all results from a PDO query like this:

```
$orders = $ordersQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now, I would like to count how many rows there are where the field 'status' is equal to 'OPEN'. I know I could just build my SQL directly to load only the OPEN status rows, but I thought it might be faster using PHP with something like

```
$openOrders = count(array_keys($orders,"OPEN"));
```

It is returning 0 though.

Comment: That should return a multidimensional array, have you tried looping over the results? Or checking to see what `$orders` looks like using `vardump();`?

Comment: 1- how do you know there's more than 0 rows? 2- are you sure you don't need array_values instead?

Comment: Without knowing how `$orders` looks like, we can't help you.

Comment: Why do you think it's faster to transfer many records from the database into memory and have PHP loop over it? As opposed to just having the database look at its index (you have one, right?) and give you a number? Unless you need the rest of the data in PHP as well, **do it in the database.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to sql, filtering results in a datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172329/linq-to-sql-filtering-results-in-a-datagridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, here's how I'd do it in PHP:

```
$orders = $ordersQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$open = array_reduce($orders, function ($num, array $order) {
    return $num + (int)($order['status'] == 'OPEN');
}, 0);
```

And here's how to actually do it:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE status = 'OPEN'";
```

Comment: I was trying to run a second query on the db. What is more efficient?

Comment: I keep getting an error with this code... "syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION "

Comment: Then you're on PHP 5.2-. Please see the manual for the appropriate syntax without anonymous functions. http://php.net/array_reduce Or rewrite it to use a loop.